# JQuery UI autocomplete disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

When using JQuery UI's autocomplete, the dropdown results appear to never appear. However, when debugging, the list appears for a short number of statements before disappearing. My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" class="myautocomplete" />
<script>
    $(document).load(function(){initializeAutocomplete()});
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
function initializeAutocomplete() {
    $('.myautocomplete').autocomplete({delay: 300, minLength: 2, source: autocomplete});
}

function autocomplete(request, responseCallback) {
    var dataUrl = "http://something.com/Suggestions.json?search_string=" + request.term;
    var suggestions = [];
    $.getJSON(dataUrl, function(json) {
        $.each(json.AutoSuggestions, function(index) {
            suggestions.push(this.SearchTerm);
        });
    });
    responseCallback(suggestions);
}
```

What is causing the autocomplete list to instantly disappear?

Comment: What does `responseCallback` do?

Comment: According to the JQuery doc, http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source, it is meant to be called with an array of strings which are to be used to create the list. It is implemented by JQuery.

Comment: I understand the callback mechanism, I'm referring to the invocation of the function `responseCallback(suggestions);` which is outside the callback mechanism and most likely causing your issue.  Does it append the returned values to your autocomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `getJSON` is async, so the `responseCallback` function is called when the array is empty, move the function after the each loop inside the getJSON function.

Try change it in:

```
function initializeAutocomplete() {
    $('.myautocomplete').autocomplete({delay: 300, minLength: 2, source: autocomplete});
}

function autocomplete(request, responseCallback) {
    var dataUrl = "http://something.com/Suggestions.json?search_string=" + request.term;
    var suggestions = [];
    $.getJSON(dataUrl, function(json) {
        $.each(json.AutoSuggestions, function(index) {
            suggestions.push(this.SearchTerm);
        });
        responseCallback(suggestions);
    });
}
```